# How to convert PFX certificate to PEM certificate in TypeScript (by using openssl or any other package)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, openssl, pem, pfx

I'm working on converting a PFX certificate to PEM certificate and would like to use TypeScript to achieve above actions. I've researched about the some npm packages but none of them come across to me as a solution. Some packages could not be found in TypeScript etc...

If there is no packages can do the conversion, I hope to find a package that can execute openssl command so I can execute the conversion command on it.

Thank you for reading and appreciates if anyone could help!